# How to Start a Process Without Losing Focus

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, start-process

I am starting a new process using the following code:

```
    Dim procStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
    Dim procExecuting As New Process

    With procStartInfo
        .FileName = "C:\PTL\Bin\xxxxxx.exe"
        .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
        .Arguments = "/POLL:5"
    End With

    procExecuting = Process.Start(procStartInfo)
```

But when this is called the application I am calling it from loses focus (even if the window style is set to Hidden), so if I am typing in a text box on the form key presses are effectively lost because they are redirected to the new app.

Is there some way that I can start a process and keep the focus?

Answer (score 0):

you need to call windows API to hide the window created from the process. check:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/vbgeneral/thread/7dace225-e4d0-4b0e-b61b-fceb7a5a4860

Comment: I don't actually want to hide it though, I just don't want the focus going to the other app

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send keys into the textbox, use sendmessage.

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendmessage